# Abstract Algebra .. Homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

let $R$ be subring of $Z_6$ consisting of all multiples of 2 . Show that $R$ is isomorphic to $Z_3$

Hint:( in order to decide how to define your function , determine the multiplicative identity of $R$ , and use the fact that subjective homomorphism must preserve multiplicative identity.)

I don't know how to use this hint to answer the question

please help me

Answer (score 1):

Note that $R = \{0, 2, 4\}$.  Obviously, $0$ is the additive identity in $R$, and it is easy to check that $4$ is the multiplicative identity:

$$2 \cdot 4 \equiv 2 \pmod{6}$$ 
$$4 \cdot 4 \equiv 4 \pmod{6}$$

From here, we can explicitly construct a surjective homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_6 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_3$ as follows:

$$\phi(4) = 1$$
$$\phi(2) = 2$$
$$\phi(0) = 0$$

I'll leave it to you to show that this is indeed a homomorphism.  I.e. you should check that it satisfies $\phi(a+b) = \phi(a) + \phi(b)$ and further, $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$.

From here, we note that we have a surjective homomorphism between two rings of equal finite cardinality.  Therefore, our homomorphism is bijective (an isomorphism), and we conclude that $R \cong \mathbb{Z}_3$.